# Ubuntu: shell script in "Startup Applications"

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I have a simple shell script on my Ubuntu guest OS (running via VirtualBox): called "add_share.sh"
I can run it using sudo (i am not root user on Ubuntu)
So i'm trying to add this script in autorun ("Dash home" -> "Startup Applications"):

```
bash /home/rusty/add_share.sh
```

Permissions for script file are: -rwxrwxr-x
But script doesn't run after system reboot. I think that problem is in non-root access, so what should i do? Can i add this script to autorun without login as root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add to the sudoers file (/etc/sudoers):
yourusername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/rusty/add_share.sh

Comment: While I don't have a better answer for you right now; please don't do as suggested here.

Comment: and if i want to grant no password sudo run for all programs this should look like "yourusername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" ?

Comment: And i think that root of my problem is script body: sudo mount -t vboxsf VMShare VMShare. Linux simply doesn't get passwd so mount is failed.